# How to require other CoffeeScripts files in main CoffeeScript with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, laravel-elixir

I have one CoffeeScript project with "Ruby on Rails" framework. Now I want to use "Laravel" framework instead of "Ruby on Rails".

In "Ruby on Rails", there is "Sprocket" asset pipeline management library. With "Sprocket", I can import other coffeescript files in main coffeescript file with `#= require` or `#= require_tree` statement e.g.

```
#= require views/view
#= require_tree ./views

#= require_tree ./templates

init = ->
  document.removeEventListener 'DOMContentLoaded', init, false

  if document.body
    app.init()
  else
    setTimeout(init, 42)
```

What are the counterparts on Laravel for these `#= require` and `#= require_tree` statements? Is there any other ways to solve this problem with Elixir?

Comment: Coffescript doesn't support native import. You can try and use Gulp to concatenate your files before compiling them. https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp-concat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there is no answer, I have to explore the solution by myself and here is the one.

In `Laravel-elixir` version (2.3.6), there is a concatenation feature for `coffeescript`. You have to store `coffeescript` files in `resources/assets/coffee` directory. Then, the following script in `gulpfile.js` will generate a single `app.js` that compile and concatenate all coffeescripts in the provided array parameter.

```
elixir(function(mix) {
   mix.coffee(['app.coffee', 'collection.coffee']);
});
```

So, you don't need to include **other coffeescript files** in **main coffeescript file** like in Sprocket of Ruby on Rails.

But there is still one issue that how to require all `coffeescript` files in more than one directory. These coffeescript files should also be **in order** so that their dependencies don't broken. It is cumbersome to write each coffeescript file name **in order** to be required. The following script can perfectly solve this issue.

```
mix.coffee([
    'lib/license.coffee',
    'lib/*.coffee',

    'app/app.coffee',
    'app/config.coffee',
    'app/*.coffee',

    'collections/collection.coffee',
    'collections/*.coffee',

    'models/model.coffee',
    'models/*.coffee',

    'views/view.coffee',
    'views/*.coffee',

    'templates/*.coffee',

    'application.coffee'
]);

mix.scripts(null, 'public/js/vendor.js', 'resources/assets/coffee/vendor');
```

You can require all coffeescript files in directory with *(asterisk) sign like that `'models/*.coffee'`.

You can also specify the file that should be required at first before requiring all the files in directory,  by their filename like that `'models/model.coffee'`. Laravel-elixir is intelligent enough to not compile and concatenate that file again.

That's the way how I solved the problem in my question.